# Tests failing on ci when using joda time

Tags: android, jodatime

My tests started failing when I run them on CI server they run normally on my machine. I am getting assertion error on this line

```
assertEquals(DateTime(1554091200000), generateNextTime())
```

I get error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :2019-04-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
Actual   :2019-03-31T20:00:00.000-04:00
```

Comment: Your test is correct that the actual value is wrong. Your millisecond value is equal to Monday 1. April 2019 04:00:00 UTC, or 00:00:00 at UTC offset -04:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_554_091_200_000L )
```

## Always specify time zone

You have learned that date-time classes fall back to implicitly applying your JVM’s current default time zone when you fail to specify one. This means your results may vary at runtime. Even worse, your results may vary *during* runtime, as any code in any thread of any app within the JVM can [change that default](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone))!

Better to always specify your desired/expected time zone. And if crucial to your app, confirm the zone with the user.

Even better yet: Focus on working in UTC. Use a time zone only where required by business logic or for presentation to user.

### `ZoneId`

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

## Joda-Time

You should know that the excellent Joda-Time project is now in maintenance-mode. Its creator, Stephen Colebourne, used the lessons learned there to go on to found JSR 310 and its implementation, the *java.time* classes.

See bullets below for older Android and Java.

The `java.time.Instant` class represents a moment in UTC. Internally, it is a count of nanoseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_554_091_200_000L ) ;

ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Puerto_Rico" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z )
```

The `Instant` and the `ZonedDateTime` both represent the same moment, the same point on the timeline. That same simultaneous moment is displayed differently, as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/wneK5e).

> instant.toString(): 2019-04-01T04:00:00Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2019-04-01T00:00-04:00[America/Puerto_Rico]

## `Clock`

For better testing, pass alternate [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) objects as the optional argument to various methods. See the `Clock` class to get clocks that are [stuck on a certain moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#fixed(java.time.Instant,java.time.ZoneId)), or that [lag behind the true time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#offset(java.time.Clock,java.time.Duration)), or [use a different cadence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#tick(java.time.Clock,java.time.Duration)) such as incrementing at the rate of a [whole second](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#tickSeconds(java.time.ZoneId)) or [whole minute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#tickMinutes(java.time.ZoneId)).

## Search Stack Overflow

Search Stack Overflow. All these topics have been addressed many many times already.

Tip: use a internet search engine such as DuckDuckGo with a criterion of `site:stackoverflow.com`. The search facility within Stack Overflow is anemic, faulty, and biased towards looking at Questions rather than Answers.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Wow, that's an exhausting post, I will check that JSR, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically what was going on was that joda time was using different timezone then what my tests were expecting.

I solved it by adding this to my tests.

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET")))
}
```

So now I am using same TimeZone everywhere I run my tests

Comment: Not a good solution. Setting the  JVM’s current default time zone immediately affects all the code in all the apps running within the JVM. Do this only as a desperate last resort. Instead you should be using the modern *java.time* classes, and passing the optional `ZoneId` argument to various methods.